# ClassNotFoundException for FrameworkBundleAdminController in Prestashop 1.7.7.rc1 module admin controller

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop

I'm doing some tests on prestashop 1.7.7.0.rc1 and trying to create an administration controller with Symfony on a module.

I encounter a ClassNotFoundException with the `FrameworkBundleAdminController`

```php
// ht_doctrine.php

declare(strict_types=1);

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}
if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
}

class Ht_doctrine extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'ht_doctrine';
        $this->author = 'Hugues';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = ['min' => '1.7.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_];
        $this->need_instance = 0;

        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Exemple HW Doctrine');
        $this->description = $this->l('Demonstration des entités Doctrine');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install()
            && $this->registerHook('displayHome');
    }
    public function uninstall()
    {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }
    public function getContent()
    {
        Tools::redirectAdmin(
            $this->context->link->getAdminLink('AdminHtDoctrineQuote')
        );
    }
    public function hookDisplayHome()
    {
        $this->smarty->assign(['quotes' => []]);
        return $this->fetch('module:ht_doctrine/views/templates/hooks/quotes.tpl');
    }
}
```

```yaml
# config/routes.yml
htdoctrine_quote_index:
    path: /htdoctrine/quotes
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Prestashop\Module\HtDoctrine\Controller\Admin\QuotesController::indexAction'
        _legacy_controller: 'AdminHtDoctrineQuote'
        _legacy_link: 'AdminHtDoctrineQuote'
```

```php
// src/Controller/Admin/QuotesController.php
<?php
namespace Prestashop\Module\HtDoctrine\Controller\Admin;

use PrestashopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class QuotesController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
{
    public function indexAction(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('@Modules/ht_doctrine/views/templates/admin/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

composer.json :

```
{
  "name": "lhapaipai/htdoctrine",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Prestashop\\Module\\HtDoctrine\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "prepend-autoloader": false,
  },
  "type": "prestashop-module"
}
```

before I want to use this module, I write :

```sh
rm -rf var/cache/dev
cd modules/ht_doctrine
composer dump-autoload
```

I try to navigate to my conf page and It's ok ! BUT if I refresh the page, I have an error message from Symfony.

```
Attempted to load class "FrameworkBundleAdminController" from namespace "PrestashopBundle\Controller\Admin".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController"?
```

ClassNotFoundException
in modules/ht_doctrine/src/Controller/Admin/QuotesController.php (line 7)

```
    namespace Prestashop\Module\HtDoctrine\Controller\Admin;
    use PrestashopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
--> class QuotesController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController
    {
        public function indexAction(): Response
        {
            return $this->render('@Modules/ht_doctrine/views/templates/admin/index.html.twig');
        }
```

If I clear the cache it's ok, but for one try.. after I encounter this error again.
do you have any idea what i missed ?
I didn't do any `composer` action at the root of the project.
I do not understand very well how the composer.json file of the module and the main composer.json file interact with each other.

Thank you for your ideas !

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from a forgotten capital letter in my namespace (Presta**S**hop)...

`use PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;`

instead of bad : `use PrestashopBundle\Controller\Admin\FrameworkBundleAdminController;`